# Displaying links from array (node.js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I set up an express-server in node.js. It should send links as a response that link to the directories in a specified folder. That part works, I get an array with all my folder like that:

```
["randomfolder","test123"]
```

Now I want to convert that array to something like that:

```
currentWebAdress/folderfromarray1<br>currentWebAdress/folderfromarray1<br>currentWebAdress/folderfromarray1
```

and then send it as a response.

How would I do such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to build the response on server side, you have to use a template engine, e.g. EJS, where you build a .ejs like

```
<% for(let i = 0; i < dirs.length; i++) { %>
<%= dirs[i]; %>
<br/>
<% } %>
```

and then render it on server side via express:

```
res.render("path/to/your/ejs", { dirs:["randomfolder","test123"] });
```

was that your question?

Comment: That was what I was looking for! Thanks! I just added relative links in the template and then it worked for me!